# How can I rephrase these two sentences for a more natural flow?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns, paragraphs

How can I rephrase the two sentences in italics, so that it sounds and flows more naturally and doesn't sound awkward. The sentence before it are given for some context.

> But neither systems perform well in the high-dimensional, continuous and partially observable real state spaces (e.g. of sensory experiences).
>
> *Latest research highlights the role of episodic memory in such cases, suggesting the possibility of episodic RL being a potential solution to these problems. I believe, the desire to realize an artificial agent that performs well in the real-world learning conditions will drive the next frontiers of research in RL and my career goal is to work towards that objective and ultimately build an agent that closely resembles human intelligence.*

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please remember that requests for writing advice or proofreading are explicitly off-topic, as among other reasons 1) questions are ideally of general interest and of help to many people, not just one; 2) there is no single, definitive way to write anything, so any answer will be grounded in opinion as much as expertise; and 3) rarely is there adequate context provided to supply an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 2):

Latest research highlights the role of Episodic Memory in such cases suggesting the possibility of Episodic RL being a solution to these problems. It is my belief that the realization of artificial agents which perform well in real-world learning conditions will drive new frontiers of research. My career goal is to work towards that objective and ultimately to build an agent that closely resembles human intelligence.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. But I want to raise another point. In the second sentence, you have changed to, 
> "It is my belief that the realization of artificial agents... will drive new frontiers of research."

This makes it sound to me , 'research will burgeon *after* new agents have been built', while my intended meaning was "the desire to build such agents will drive the research in the next few years". 

Is this difference obvious from reading the sentences? Thanks.

Comment: @rio1210 I'd read it as saying that the act of realization (of making real) drives concurrent research. My answer to you is not necessarily definitive or authoritative and ultimately only you know how you'd like to say what you'd like to say ;)

Answer (score -1):

Same as answer above but change "which" to "that" in the second sentence for more-correct usage.

Comment: chris W, Perhaps it's because I was thinking in British English and I wanted to de-restrict the sentence to allow 'artificial agents' a little more lassitude in their success. I agree with your point.

Comment: And were you going to comment on "Neither of the systems performs..." or "Neither system performs well..." against Rio's original version?

Comment: You may want to put "same as @author's answer", since the "above" isn't consistent--answers get re-arranged based on votes.